# Postgresql mulitpy a calulated column * 6

Tags: postgresql, operators

I am getting null values when I try to multiply my generated column * 6.  I am not sure why no error codes.  Without the Last_Six_Hours column, it seems to work just fine.  Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT well_id, reported_date, 
  (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM age(reported_date,
                          LAG(reported_date) OVER w))/3600)::int AS hour_rate,
                           (hour_rate*6)::int as Last_Six_Hours

FROM public.production
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY well_id ORDER BY well_id, reported_date 
             ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW);
```

Comment: That means that `production` must have a column named `hour_rate`. You cannot reference an alias in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Seems like your table `production` already has an `hour_rate` column that it's making thing confusing. Please use a different alias for the newly created column.

Comment: Yes, I added the column hour_rate as double precision.  It is being generated here in the query.  Still getting a null when I run this.  It should be able to calculate off the previously generated row correct?

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results as text - **no images**.